# Applying background image to multiple <li>

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a background clipboard image showing behind the first list item within an `<ol>`.

I'd like it to apply to all the list items (not just the first one), I could do this by applying the class to every `<li>` but this feels unnecessary when it should work on the `<ol>` level.

[image: See background clipboard image only shows under the first list item.]

Above shows the background clipboard image only showing under the first list item. How can I get it to work on every list item?

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  counter-reset: orderedlist;
}

ol>li {
  counter-increment: orderedlist;
  padding-left: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

ol>li:before {
  content: counter(orderedlist)".";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.52em;
}

.action-item {
  background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/clipboard-1/100/clipboard-10-512.png);
  background-position: 15px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<ol class="action-item">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to assign the `.action-item` class to every `<li>` element. At the moment you only display the background image once on the `<ol>` element.

You can change the CSS rule from `.action-item` to `.action-item li` or `ol.action-item li`.

You can use the following solution:

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  counter-reset: orderedlist;
}
ol > li {
  counter-increment: orderedlist;
  padding-left: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
ol > li:before {
  content: counter(orderedlist);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.52em;
}
.action-item li {
  background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/clipboard-1/100/clipboard-10-512.png);
  background-position: 15px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<ol class="action-item">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5<br>multiline</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
</ol>
```

*Is there a way to remove the period after the number?*

You set the number with `content: counter(orderedlist)".";` There is a trailing period. Just remove the period (`"."`) to only show the numbers.

Comment: **I could do this by applying the class to every <li> but this feels unnecessary** --> he said

Comment: @TemaniAfif - The class is assigned on every `<li>` on my solution?

Comment: no but it's applied to all li ... i think it's the same [for me at least ...]

Comment: I think he don't want to write the class on every `<li>` element. He shouldn't repeat the image on `<ol>` elements (***hint:** multiline list items*).

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. that's great. Yes I didn't want to have to apply to class to every list item. Quicker if just on the ordered list level. Is there a way to remove the period after the number - there doesn't seem to be a list style for this?

Comment: just remove the period on `counter(orderedlist)".";` - see update

Comment: Thanks all sorted!

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-repeat` and adjust the size slightly:

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  counter-reset: orderedlist;
}

ol>li {
  counter-increment: orderedlist;
  padding-left: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

ol>li:before {
  content: counter(orderedlist)".";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.52em;
}

.action-item {
  background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/clipboard-1/100/clipboard-10-512.png);
  background-position: 15px 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<ol class="action-item">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your current `background-image` is not applied on the first `li`, its on the `ol`...its look like applied on first visually

Just use the `background-image` to the `li` instead if `ol` using parent class `.action-item`

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  counter-reset: orderedlist;
}

ol>li {
  counter-increment: orderedlist;
  padding-left: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.action-item>li {
  background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/clipboard-1/100/clipboard-10-512.png);
  background-position: 15px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1.4em;
}

ol>li:before {
  content: counter(orderedlist)".";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.52em;
}
```

```html
<ol class="action-item">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: **I could do this by applying the class to every <li> but this feels unnecessary** --> he said

Comment: @TemaniAfif but here I am not applying the class...just minor change in the css

Comment: i know, but i think it's the same .. i understand from this that we want to avoid applying the style to li [but maybe am wrong]

Answer (score -1):

Everything ok
just use .action-item li{} in place of .action-item{} like this -

`.action-item li{
      background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/clipboard-1/100/clipboard-10-512.png);
      background-position: 15px 0px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 1.4em;
}`

Comment: I think you r overflow with answers. i am sorry to try you help